# Wubi install, lost home folder, recovery options?

Tags: wubi, home-directory

I have been running Ubuntu for over a year on my laptop and I've really come to enjoy it.  So much that it has replaced Windows in my day-to-day activities.

Yesterday an error occurred on my desktop version of 12.04 that caused it to fail to boot.  In the process, I lost the contents of my home folder despite creating a back up of the home folder.

Here is the time line:

Feb 18, 2013 - Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on desktop via Wubi.  The install went as advertised and I proceeded to apply personal tweaks to make both the laptop and the desktop essentially the same.  Everything functioned normally.

Feb 19-23 - Began moving files from the laptop to the desktop in an effort to centralize my own files.  The intent was to use Dropbox as a sort of "briefcase", and use the laptop when I needed to be mobile.

Feb 24 - Everything functioned normally through the day.  I switched to Windows to continue sending things to Dropbox as I could not see any of the Ubuntu folders in my Windows Explorer.  As this was my first dual boot experience, I assumed this was normal.

While in Windows, the HP Desktop Assistant informed me it needed to do system maintenance (I use windows only for MS Flight Sim - it is infrequent).  I delayed it by one hour.  System did not ask me again, and I assume it went ahead and did what it needed to do while files were being moved to Dropbox.

System failed to boot 12.04.  Internet research lead me to believe the GRUB2 had somehow become corrupt (possibly during the above Windows maintenance).  At this time I created a bootable USB using UNetBootin.

This gained access to a terminal where I ran "boot-repair".  Boot Repair found an issue and advised me to back up my files.  I proceeded to put the contents of my Home folder on another USB.  After this process had completed, the system became unresponsive - I could not double check that the files had actually moved.

I believed I had enough evidence that the transfer had taken place, I opted to remove Wubi, and do a true dual boot of Ubuntu in its own partition, hoping this would prevent this error from happening again.  When that had completed, I found the USB contained only the folders within my Home folder from the previous Wubi install.

I have run Photorec, as suggested below.  It recovered fragments of files, but not a whole file.  I suspect this occurred when I attempted another Wubi install in the hopes that it would locate my old home folder (this was done prior to asking for help from ask ubuntu).

I am still seeking solution, but I believe the contents of my previous Home folder are now unrecoverable.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on its own partition (now), 64 bit
Windows 7 is on the other partition (where the Wubi install was)

If any other details will be helpful, I'll be glad to provide.  Also, I'm not afraid of the command line.

**EDIT** This question can be closed.  User bcbc gave the best answer in another forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065355

If the home folder is lost during a Wubi uninstall (as mine was) then it is gone. I believe it would have been recoverable had I not attempted another Wubi install this morning (prior to asking the above question) prior to running programs that can recover deleted data.

Tough lesson to learn. Thank you to those who took the time to help out.

Comment: Congrats for _I'm not afraid of the command line._

Comment: First, stop using the drive. 2nd, what exactly is on the USB backup? 3rd, checkout http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec - it can recover data after formatting.

Comment: PhotoRec recovered only fragments of a few missing files.  Nothing substantial.  The USB back up was the entire contents of my Ubuntu home folder (Wubi installed).

Answer (score 0):

When you install ubuntu using wubi, you are installing it as and app inside windows. Anyway, in order to find your files on your usb disk, first try to check `unused space` of your usb disk. If it shows that you have your files there, then make sure that they are not hidden by any means. If you didn't have your files on your usb disk, then try to recover them using a cool tool named `testdisk`. And durin doing these steps **Don't** write anything on your usb disk, this may cause loss of data.

Comment: Folders appear under normal circumstances - as though there is actually something there.  Selecting "Show Hidden Files" brings up the various config folders that made the jump.  All folders appear empty.

Comment: Your question and your comment seems to be a little ambiguous together. If you can have your files on your usb disk then what is the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm not very good at explaining these problems.

"boot-repair" advised me to back up my home folder, which I did - or thought I did.  It did not give me the opportunity to double check that it had actually done it.  I have since come to find it took the folders, but not the contents of the folders.